# How to deselect all selected items in a WPF treeview when clicking on some empty area?

Tags: wpf

I've got a rather funny problem with WPF. I have a tree-view, and selecting items works fine so far. The problem is, I want to unselect the currently selected item when the user clicks inside the blank area of the treeview. By default, the treeview keeps the current item selected, and I have added a context-menu option to deselect it, which is rather hardcore:

```
// Note: This is done recursivly from the start, so it
// works for child items as well
treeView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(treeView.SelectedItem) as TreeViewItem).IsSelected = false;
```

Moreover, this is counter-intuitive, as it requires the user to right-click first, and second, after deselecting it with this way, the user cannot select it any more by clicking on the item. How is this supposed to work?

Edit: Some more information: I've added a handler to the `TreeView` to handle mouse click events, but the sender is always a `TreeView` instance, even if I click directly on a `TreeViewItem`. If I add a handler to my `TreeView.ItemTemplate` instead (i.e. the first child in the template), I never get events when I click on the empty area (which is rather logical). The code looks like this:

```
    private void MyTreeView_MouseUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((sender as TreeViewItem) == null)
        {
            // Always triggered
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write("Empty area clicked");
        }
    }
```

And the XAML for this is:

```
<TreeView x:Name="MyTreeView" Margin="3" MouseUp="MyTreeView_MouseUp">
```

Answer (score 7):

I found this to work much better for me.  I check the originalsource which for me if it comes form a treeviewitem will be an image or a textblock.  I also use a view object with a HierarchicalDataTemplate and the BasicTreeViewBase is the base class for all of my different objects.  Here is the code.

```
private void TemplateTreeView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Right && !(e.OriginalSource is Image) && !(e.OriginalSource is TextBlock))
        {
            BasicTreeViewBase item = TemplateTreeView.SelectedItem as BasicTreeViewBase;
            if (item != null)
            {
                TemplateTreeView.Focus();
                item.IsSelected = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: why do you need `TemplateTreeView.Focus();` ?

Comment: @DavidRefaeli that was so long ago I don't remember why I had it.  I do know that when I wrote it, it didn't work with out it.

Comment: it's a nice solution, I had to make some adjustments as you're using your own classes here I think (TemplateTreeView, BasicTreeViewBase) - but for me I don't need to change the .Focus() in order to deselect the item.

Comment: If you're binding to an ItemsSource and, therefore, "SelectedItem" is not a TreeViewItem, but whatever object ItemSource consists of... in your TreeView, add TreeViewItem.Selected="event_name" and then track which TreeViewItem is selected so that later you can set IsSelected=false on the TreeViewItem explicitly.

Answer (score 5):

The un-selectable problem can be solved with a call to Focus on the TreeView after setting TreeViewItem.IsSelected.

Comment: Nice, Good Catch!
I was wondering why I wasn't able to select the same node once it was unselected.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There can be two more problem :

1. The treeview is binded so the SelectedItem is an item of the binded collection.
2. There is many levels so ItemContainerGenerator do not contain deepest level objects

for all this reason i use this function, but the selection must not fire any events.

```
private void UnselectTreeViewItem(TreeView pTreeView)
{ 
  if(pTreeView.SelectedItem == null)
    return;

  if(pTreeView.SelectedItem is TreeViewItem)
  {
    (pTreeView.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem).IsSelected = false;
  }
  else
  {
    TreeViewItem item = pTreeView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0) as TreeViewItem;
    if (item != null)
    {
      item.IsSelected = true;
      item.IsSelected = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I implemented a general selection control once, and required this behaviour.

This is how my method looked (adapted for treeview):

```
protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseUp(e);

    DependencyObject dpSource = e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject;

    if (dpSource.FindVisualAncestor(o => typeof(TreeViewItem).IsAssignableFrom(o.GetType())) == null)
            UnselectAll();
}
```

Basically, walk up the tree from the source. If a TreeViewItem was not found, than the user clicked empty space.

Answer (score 2):

Use the extension class below

```
public static class TreeViewExtensions
{
    public static TreeViewItem ContainerFromItem(this TreeView treeView, object item)
    {
        TreeViewItem containerThatMightContainItem = (TreeViewItem)treeView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
        if (containerThatMightContainItem != null)
            return containerThatMightContainItem;
        else
            return ContainerFromItem(treeView.ItemContainerGenerator, treeView.Items, item);
    }

    private static TreeViewItem ContainerFromItem(ItemContainerGenerator parentItemContainerGenerator, ItemCollection itemCollection, object item)
    {
        foreach (object curChildItem in itemCollection)
        {
            TreeViewItem parentContainer = (TreeViewItem)parentItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(curChildItem);
            TreeViewItem containerThatMightContainItem = (TreeViewItem)parentContainer.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
            if (containerThatMightContainItem != null)
                return containerThatMightContainItem;

            TreeViewItem recursionResult = ContainerFromItem(parentContainer.ItemContainerGenerator, parentContainer.Items, item);
            if (recursionResult != null)
                return recursionResult;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then in MouseDown event of treeview use the extension method as below:

```
    private void trview_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((sender as TreeViewItem) == null)
        {
            if (this.trview.ContainerFromItem(trview.SelectedItem) != null)
            {
                this.trview.ContainerFromItem(trview.SelectedItem).IsSelected = false;
            }
        }
        this.trview.Focus();
    }
```

Hope it works for you. I have it working in this way...

Answer (score 2):

I was running into this situation myself with a custom Tree List View implementation after looking for a long time I finally found a solution that worked for me.

The full explanation can be found at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/36aca7f7-0b47-488b-8e16-840b86addfa3/getting-treeviewitem-for-the-selected-item-in-a-treeview

The basic idea is you capture the `TreeViewItem.Selected` event and save the source of the event into the `Tag` attribute on your TreeView. Then when you need to clear it, you can access the `Tag` attribute on your control and set the `IsSelected` value to False. This works for me with 2 levels of nested children. Hopefully it will work for you.

For persistence sake:

TreeView declaration

```
  <TreeView Name="myTreeView" TreeViewItem.Selected="OnItemSelected"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myHierarchicalData}}"/>
```

Event Handler

```
private void OnItemSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myTreeView.Tag = e.OriginalSource;
}
```

Clear selection logic

```
if (myTreeView.SelectedItem != null)
{
    TreeViewItem selectedTVI = myTreeView.Tag as TreeViewItem;
    // add your code here mine was selectedTVI.IsSelected = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will deselect the currently selected TreeViewItem if none were clicked:

```
private void MyTreeView_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    if ((sender as TreeViewItem) == null) {
        TreeViewItem item = MyTreeView.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem;
        if(item != null){
            item.IsSelected = false;                    
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this is what you were looking for!

Comment: Does not work, because after selecting an item, sender is bound to the currently selected item - that is, even if I click into the empty area, sender == the currently selected item.

Comment: Hmm. If you click on the TreeView itself, the sender should be a TreeView (not a TreeViewItem). Did you add this handler to the TreeView or to each TreeViewItem? Are you using the standard TreeView or a custom one?

Comment: Ahh the problem is I don't get a TreeViewItem, but rather an instance of my viewmodel class, for which I have to find the corresponding TreeViewItem. Worse still, after unselecting an item programmatically, I cannot reselect by clicking on it.

Comment: More problems, expanding an item deselects it with this approach - and I can't get it working for child items, as ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem returns null for that?

Comment: Could you edit your original post to include some more code so I can get a better idea of what's going on? Thanks!

Comment: The reason this can fail is because if tree view items are bound in MVVM, SelectedItem can be a view model class instead of a TreeViewItem.

Answer (score 0):

MVVM: Call this method in the eventhandler righ/left mouse click:

```cs
private void SetTreeViewSelection(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs mouseButtonEventArgs)
{
  var treeView = (TreeView)sender;
  if (treeView.SelectedItem == null)
  {
    return;
  }
  
  IInputElement dropNode = treeView.InputHitTest(mouseButtonEventArgs.GetPosition(treeView));
  if (dropNode is ScrollViewer)
  {
    var myBindableObject = (MyBindableObject)treeView.SelectedItem;
    myBindableObject.IsSelected = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For a C# treeview you use treeview.SelectedNode = null;  I'm not sure if this works for WPF.