# How to trigger the Selected event when I select one item everytime

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, treeviewitem

I have a `TreeView` like this:

xaml:

```
<TreeView>
     <TreeViewItem Header="header" Name="mytreeViewItem" Selected="mytreeViewItem_Selected"/>
</TreeView>
```

xaml.cs:

```
mytreeViewItem.ItemsSource = new List<string>(){"a"};
```

When I select the `TreeViewItem` nameed `a`, it will trigger event `mytreeViewItem_Selected`. But when I select the `TreeViewItem` again, it wont trigger the event again. How can I trigger the `Selected` event when I select the `TreeView` every time?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "[...]when I select the `TreeViewItem` again[...]". Are you clicking it again, while it's still selected? Are you clicking it after you deselected it? Because the `Selected` event will only fire, if it's just getting selected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PreviewMouseDown` event or something similar (`PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` for example) according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Can you have

```
item.IsSelected = false;
```

in your event handler? So when you click again, the Selected event re-fires. I don't think it will fire if the same is still selected.

Comment: Sorry. I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389797/unselecting-and-reselecting-a-treeviewitem-in-a-treeview, which might be a workaround for you, and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491111/how-to-deselect-all-selected-items-in-a-wpf-treeview-when-clicking-on-some-empty.